# In ETS packages can you use high frequency f=365..?

Tags: r, tableau-api, forecasting, ets

I am using forecast function ..and ts() ,using F=365.........AND able to see gud day wise seasonality..in Hyndman sir blog I read "I am often asked how to fit an ARIMA or ETS model with data hav­ing a long sea­sonal period such as 365 for daily data or 48 for half-​​hourly data. Gen­er­ally, sea­sonal ver­sions of ARIMA and ETS mod­els are designed for shorter peri­ods such as 12 for monthly data or 4 for quar­terly data"    as in stackoverflow, I got to know that forecast() simply use ETS Function..what is correct ..

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using R, you can do the same thing in the Tableau workbook. Right-click your forecast area and select Describe Forecast... This will give you all of your quality metrics as well.

[image]

Comment: yes,actually i have already done this...but  tableau inbuilt forecasting dont use exponential smoothing ...in demand forecasting exponential smoothing is good that take care of trend seasons error cyclic..so i used forecast package R in tableau.... and i used f=365..but for hourly data ...multiple seasonality was missing in ts ()..cud u further suggest